# LinqPad Data at the root level is invalid

Tags: linq, linqpad

I am trying to execute linq command `Users.Take (50)` and get error "`Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."`. Why?

Comment: That looks like a XML error. Do you have any xml columns in the user table and do they all have valid data?

Comment: Yes, one of table field has XML data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing one of the first 50 records contains something that isn't true XML.

Note, SQL will allow you to save simple text to these columns, so if you have values like `<Name>Joe</Name>` this will display correctly in C#/VB, but values like `Joe` won't.

Answer (score 1):

> get error `"Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."`. Why?

b/c it's not valid XML

**Workaround**

On your connection, you can:

> Map XML columns to .NET strings instead of XElements

[image: screenshot of how to treat XML as strings]